# Advanced Find & Replace in MSWord

Tags: ms-word

I have a frequency dictionary that I copied into MsWord.

I am looking to import this into SuperMemo (A spaced-repetition memory program similar to Anki).

I bulk of the document looks like:

> 93 | 151709 11 dans prep in, into, from * je reviendrai dans dix minutes -- I will return in 10 minutes 93 | 161033 12 ce det,pro this, that * je ne déteste pas cet homme -- I do not detest this man 87 | 307421 13 il pro he, it * allez voir s'il est blessé -- go see if he is injured 86 | 251585 14 qui pro who, whom * je ne sais pas à qui m'adresser -- I don't know who to talk to

I would like to find a way to find and replace the numbers bordering the "|" as well as the "|" sign itself. Additionally I would like to place each word on its own line, essentiall pressing return before the "string of numbers" + "|".

I correctly edited document would look like:

> 11 dans prep in, into, from * je reviendrai dans dix minutes -- I will return in 10 minutes
>   12 ce det,pro this, that * je ne déteste pas cet homme -- I do not detest this man
>   13 il pro he, it * allez voir s'il est blessé -- go see if he is injured
>  
>   14 qui pro who, whom * je ne sais pas à qui m'adresser -- I don't know who to talk to

Comment: Have you tried some of the steps in [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What to do

In the Find and Replace box:

- Check the Use Wildcards checkbox
- In the Find What box put `<[0-9]@ | [0-9]@>`
- In the Replace With box put `^l`
- Click Replace All

## How it works

You can find al lthe special characters by clicking the Special button on the Find and Replace box.  Basically:

- `^l` is a manual line break (the same as you get by pressing return
- `[0-9]` means any character that is a digit
- `[0-9]@` means 1 or more digits
- `<[0-9]@` means 1 or more digits including the beginning of the word
- `<[0-9]@ | [0-9]@>` means a word of digits, a space, a pipe, a space and a word of digits